extjs versions later than 7.6 have problems dragging tabs
When I was using the plugin "boxreorderer", I found a serious animation problem with drag and drop ordering. As the drag component moved to the right, the other components kept moving back and forth left and right, stopping automatically for an unknown amount of time. So I looked at the official case and found that there was also this problem, so I recorded the screen for this.
Click to play video
I tried version 7.5.1 is normal, but in version 7.6 and above have this problem.
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    height: headHeight,
    border: 0,
    overflowHandler: 'menu',
    items: headItems,
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'boxreorderer',
    }],
});


This could be a bug if their own example is working incorrectly, consider reporting it. Meanwhile you can disable animation with plugins: [{ptype: 'tabreorderer',animate: false}] which is not nice but solves the problem. If you check the startDrag function in source code you see some comments about a workaround but I don't know if it is relevant.

How do report this bug?

If you have a subscription, contact Sencha Support. If you don't, I don't know how to report a bug.

My temporary solution
Ext.override(Ext.ux.BoxReorderer, {     doSwap: function () {         if (this.doSwaping) {             return;         }         this.callParent(arguments);         this.doSwaping = true;         setTimeout(() => {             this.doSwaping = false;         }, this.animate + 100);     } });
hope the authorities can solve it soon.
